# How to show Background rendering and Event background at a same time slot in Fullcalandar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am working on Calendar using a `Fullcalendar` library.

I need to show multiple `Background Event` at the same time slot.
I didn't find any related solution for it.

#### Want to show background event as `side-by-side` like a normal event.

#### What I have tried?

I have added this `slotEventOverlap` negative to show the events differently and separate them at the same time. it works for "Norma" event but not for `Background event`

But this is not working on `Background Events`

```
 slotEventOverlap:false,
```

Please pass your valuable response to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: This is not possible. A background event loses its shape and just changes the colour of the whole area of the calendar where its time period. There is no setting to change this.

Comment: By the way your screenshots are a bit confusing. Background events have no text in them, yet your screenshot shows text over the top. Did you add that yourself with some extra code? It's not clear. When asking a question here it's always best to show the code and data as well so that we can fully understand how the result you are showing has occurred.

Comment: @ADyson in my case this is an appointment of a related doctor so I have added the text related to that. actually there is 3 different appointment for 3 different users at 9 to 1-time slot.

Comment: @ADyson so I am thinking of showing 3 background events for each at that timeslot. (as we see it will only show one - in left side) when it becomes background event.

Comment: If you want them to contain text then why do you want them as background events? I don't understand the purpose of this. What's the problem with using them as normal (non-background) events?

Comment: @ADyson in my case sometimes we add another event add by clicking on that, so if it in the background then it's easier to simply select and add another event at that time.

Comment: I see. Because it's hard to select in the tiny space remaining, you mean? I understand that. However, what you're asking for with the background events is simply impossible with the way that fullCalendar works currently. Perhaps you could make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) or even [submit your own patch](https://fullcalendar.io/contributing)

Comment: @ADyson ok I understand thanks sir for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 7):

**Update**
You need to use the `rendering: 'background'` in separate events with just starting and endpoint. like this

```
events: [
  {
     resourceId: "a",
     start: '2019-11-16T04:00:00',
     end: '2019-11-16T10:00:00',
     rendering: 'background'
  },
]
```

And when you want to show other event inside this colored block you need to define new events like this.

```
events: [

      // set background for a block.
      {
        resourceId: "a",
        start: '2019-11-16T04:00:00',
        end: '2019-11-16T10:00:00',
        rendering: 'background'
      },

      // Main events to show inside the colored block.
      {
        resourceId: "a",
        title: 'Business Lunch',
        start: '2019-11-16T06:00:00',
        end: '2019-11-16T08:00:00',
        color: '#551e4a'
      },
      {
        resourceId: "a",
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2019-11-16T06:00:00',
        end: '2019-11-16T08:00:00',
        color: '#159e4a'
      },
      {
        resourceId: "a",
        title: 'Reporting',
        start: '2019-11-16T06:00:00',
        end: '2019-11-16T08:00:00',
        color: '#159eff'
      },
    ]
```

I think you need to use `eventOverlap: false,` instead of `slotEventOverlap: false,`.

Check the demo for better info

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/WNNYyda)**

So this is the output of side by side events that these codes provide.

[image]

```js
$(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaDay'
    },
    eventOverlap : false,
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    resources: [
      { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
      { id: 'b', title: 'Room B'}
    ],

    events: [
      {
        resourceId: "a",
        start: '2019-11-16T04:00:00',
        end: '2019-11-16T10:00:00',
        rendering: 'background'
      },
      {
        resourceId: "a",
        title: 'Business Lunch',
        start: '2019-11-16T06:00:00',
        end: '2019-11-16T08:00:00',
        color: '#551e4a'
      },
      {
        resourceId: "a",
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2019-11-16T06:00:00',
        end: '2019-11-16T08:00:00',
        color: '#159e4a'
      },
      {
        resourceId: "a",
        title: 'Reporting',
        start: '2019-11-16T06:00:00',
        end: '2019-11-16T08:00:00',
        color: '#159eff'
      },
    ]
  });
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', '2019-11-16');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

#calendar a.fc-event {
  color: #fff; /* bootstrap default styles make it black. undo */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment@2.24.0/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@3.10.1/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: My issue is with the Background event.
Add  `rendering: 'background'` in your events then check it, it will show only one event. @Nasser

Comment: @always-a-learner can you update the demo to show your issue?

Comment: @always-a-learner answer updated please check, I hope it solve your issue.

Comment: If you want to set the color for just an event then use the `color` but if you want to give the background color to a group of events you need to set it for a dummy event that covers your events. @always-a-learner

Comment: Here is my side of work looks like.
https://www.screencast.com/t/B5Ty5176V

In my case, the background events will convert and become normal events
Currently, I am not able to click on it and select.

Comment: @always-a-learner You need to add the event click like this `eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
      alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
    },` and as I checked it works fine in demo https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/NWWJXRQ?editors=0010, may you have some other mistakes. Please provide clear details about your issues, and if possible a demo.

Comment: @always-a-learner Here is another example with time slot selection that works fine.https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/PooLEmL?editors=0010

Comment: I will add a demo of my issue sir, thanks for your support

Answer (score 2):

I'm supposing that you have three events like this

```
{ 
id: 1,
title: "Apointments : Appointment 1",
start: "2019-10-27T10:00:00",
end: "2019-10-27T19:00:00",
allDay: false 
}
{
id: 2,
title: "Apointments : Appointment 2",
start: "2019-10-27T10:00:00",
end: "2019-10-27T19:00:00",
allDay: false 
}
{
id: 3
title: "Apointments : Appointment 3",
start: "2019-10-27T10:00:00",
end: "2019-10-27T19:00:00",
allDay: false 
}
```

try to Merge all three events into one by date and time and append all title into one title like this

```
{
id: 1,
title: "Apointments : Appointment 1, Appointment 2, Appointment 3",
start: "2019-10-27T10:00:00",
end: "2019-10-27T19:00:00",
allDay: false 
}
```

so when you will retrieve on the front end it will be showing like this

[image: so when you will retrieve on the front end it will be showing like this]

I was facing the same issue long before and managed to solve like this.

Comment: is this rendering as "Background Event" ?

have you added `rendering: 'background',`